# Least Angle Regression (LARS) without Matrix Inversion

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, least-squares, convex-optimization

Sorry if this is too damned long. I did what I could to abbreviate it.

The question is about [Least Angle Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-angle_regression) (LARS).

I'm new to numerical work with matrices.

I believe I have a way to compute Least Angle without explicit matrix inversion. I'm hoping someone with more experience can check my work to see if I'm doing anything dangerous, illegal, or otherwise ignorant.

This paper: [Least Angle Regression](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/LARS/LeastAngle_2002.pdf), says:

> "...we compute $m−k$ inner products $c_{jk}$ of the non-active $x_j$
>   with the current residuals to identify the next active variable, and
>   then **invert** the $k \times  k$ matrix $\mathcal{G}_k = X'_kX_k$ to
>   find the next LARS direction."

(Emphasis mine.)

They update the Cholesky decomposition in each iteration, so it seems they're doing something like this:

- At $k$th iteration:
- $X_k$ is a matrix formed from $k$ predictors.
- $X'_k X_k = \mathcal{G}_{k}$
- We already have $\mathcal{G}_{k-1}$, and $\mathcal{G}_{k} = \mathcal{G}_{k-1}$ except for a new row and column of dot products, so let's say $$\mathcal{G}_{k} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathcal{G}_{k-1} & \mathbf{p} \\
  \mathbf{p}' & x \end{array} \right]$$
- We can find the Cholesky decomposition $L_k$ from $L_{k-1}$:
  $$L_{k} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  L_{k-1} & \mathbf{r}=L_{k-1}^{-1}\mathbf{p} \\
  \mathbf{r}' & y=(x - \mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r})^{-\frac12} \end{array} \right]$$
- Find $L_k^{-1}$. **Note this explicit inversion.**
- $\mathcal{G}^{-1}_k = {L'}_k^{-1} L_k^{-1}$
- $A_k = (1'_k \mathcal{G}^{-1}_k 1_k)^{-\frac12}$, where $1_k$ is a vector of $k$ 1s.
- ${\mathbf w}_k = A_k {\mathcal G}_k^{-1} 1_k$
- Use ${\mathbf w}_k$ to select the $(k+1)$th predictor.

**Now here's my approach**:

- At $k$th iteration:
- Find $L_k$, $\mathbf{r}$, and $y$ as above
- Define $L_k {\mathbf q}_k = 1_k$
- Find $\mathbf{q}_k$:
  $${\mathbf q}_{k} = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
  {\mathbf q}_{k-1} \\
  \text{$\scriptsize{(1 - {\mathbf q}_{k-1} \cdot \mathbf{r})/y}$} \end{array} \right]$$
- $\begin{align}A_k &= (1'_k \mathcal{G}^{-1}_k 1_k)^{-\frac12} \\
                       &= (1'_k L'{_k}^{-1} L_k^{-1} 1_k)^{-\frac12} \\
                       &= \left[(L_k^{-1} 1_k)' (L_k^{-1} 1_k)\right]^{-\frac12} \\
                       &= ({\mathbf q}'_k {\mathbf q}_k)^{-\frac12} \end{align}$
- $\begin{align}{\mathbf w}_k &= A_k {\mathcal G}_k^{-1} 1_k \\
                                 &= A_k L'{_k}^{-1} {\mathbf q}_k \end{align}$
- So solve for ${\mathbf w}_k$: $\frac{1}{A_k} L'_k {\mathbf w}_k = {\mathbf q}_k$

Comments? Does it even matter if I'm right?

Comment: This is a very specialized question, so it may be difficult or take a while to get a good answer. Do you seem to get the same answers with both approaches?

Comment: As I see $L_k$ is a matrix where as $1_k$ is a column vector. Therefore, you cannot break the matrix into two vectors and then take inverse of vectors in 3rd step of decomposing $A_k$.

Comment: Yes Jason, I get the same answers with both approaches. learner, I have removed the offending line. It was inconsequential. I have also rearranged the steps to match what my implementation actually does.

Comment: Your link to the paper is broken

Comment: That's weird. Somehow the address was abbreviated with ellipses. Fixed now.

Comment: Are you really after the whole path or a specific LASSO solution?

Comment: @Royi - Could you please clarify? Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the LARS is like LASSO. The extra step is to show the values of each element for different values of $ \lambda $. The question is, do you really need the whole path solution?

Comment: @Royi - Hm. It's been a long time since I was working in this area. I can tell you I just wanted the final $\mathbf{\hat\beta}$ but I don't remember much more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve for single value of $ \lambda $ in the model:

$$ \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} $$

Then you can use [Coordinate Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent) method which is the fastest and simplest and doesn't require any matrix inversion.

I have a MATLAB code for in my [$ {L}_{1} $ Regularized Least Squares Analysis GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects):

[image]